# Slow query with 22 million points

Tags: influxdb

I have 1 TB (text data).
I installed the Influxd, in a machine (240 G RAM, 32 CUP)
I only inserted around 22 million points in one measurement, one tag and 110 field.
When i do query (select id from ts limit 1) , it exceed 20 second, and this is not good.
So can you please help me in what i should do to have a good performance

Comment: What exactly did you select as tag?
Perhaps give us a brief description of the data (schema) to help you structure it better.
You select one or more tags to group/distinguish datapoints that somehow logically belong to some groups or categories. You don't need a different tag value for each datapoint. What you want to achieve is that timestamp + tag1 + tag2 ... is a unique key, then you will not have any overwrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many count your series?
maybe your problem come up from here: 
  https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#don-t-have-too-many-series

> Tags containing highly variable information like UUIDs, hashes, and random strings will lead to a large number of series in the database, known colloquially as high series cardinality. High series cardinality is a primary driver of high memory usage for many database workloads

Comment: I think you are right, the only tag is the unique value, so its 22 million series. But what i have to do in this case, because when i select another column to be tag, i see lot of points overwrite, because the time value is not unique.

Comment: Why you want to use tags? May you tell more specific.

Comment: Because our time value repeated over points, if i do not use tags, lot of points will be overwrite, that's why I'm using tag to prevent this data overwrite. You know that the unique key in Influx world is measurement+time+tags

Comment: More details:  For the time i already have time value in my data, but this value can be repeated, so i have to add tags, but adding more and more tags create lot of series, I dont know what is the best solution here ? I have only one table (measurement) with 110 column (tag or field).
Its very hard to check the combination between tags to find a unique value, the easy solution to put only one tag which is the primary key for my table, and this will create series by number of all rows which is 3 billion row :frowning_face:

Comment: Well, this is obviously not the "easy solution" because it is not a solution at all ... as you have already experienced.
If you know your data then you don't have to check all combinations of tags. Where do the datapoints come from? A device; then maybe used the device id as tag. A user; then use the user id as a tag. Assuming a device/user cannot produce more than one datapoint at certain time, then you should not have overlap, and you won't have 3 billion series.

Comment: Oh ok. I used influx in nanosecond scale still some of my measurment not have tags. So I can have 1 billion point per second. And for getting record I used time in query i.e I used time for object id. Now I don't know  this can help you to avoid using of tags for avoid overwriting record or not.

Comment: Great, Thanks Mahdi and Nikolay